# iOS App Store get crash reports

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iOS App on the app store, and I see there is crahes on multiple dates, but couldn't find the crash log or report ?

Where can I find it to help me fix the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Open the `Organizer` Window (Shortcut: Command-Shift-6) in Xcode and select your App archive and then the `Crashes` tab at the top. All crash information is then downloaded into Xcode.

Comment: does it show specifics like what method caused the crash ?

Comment: From my experience, yes. You get a full backtrace and the editor shows code locations, etc.